# YouTube OAuth2 authorization fails on reauthorization

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I've created my own OAuth2 client to connect to the google API (specifically YouTube). All works as expected the first time I authorise:

- I do a `POST` to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` with appropriate parameters (`response_type=code`, `redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`, etc)
- I handle the response in a UIWebView, letting the user go through the login dialogs
- I fetch the **authorization code** needed for requesting the token from the title on the final page
- I do the token request `POST` to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`
- I get the access_token and refresh_token and such which I store in my application

However, I have a sign-off button and this is where the problem is occurring; this basically sets the `access_token` and `refresh_token` which i've stored in my application back to `nil`, simply so:

```
- (void)clearCredentials
{
    _accessToken = nil;
    _refreshToken = nil;
    _tokenExpirationDate = nil;
}
```

When I then want to log in again, I call the same authorization method as before, all parameters are correctly set like the first time. 
However, on going through the login dialogs, I don't get the page where I would grant the application to access the youtube account, and thus also not get the page where I can fetch the authorization code from the page title. Instead it presents me with an error page (`invalid_request`) that says that I failed to provide a `response_type`.

I also tried revoking the `access_token`. The revoking works as intended, but upon authorization I still don't get the page where the user can approve permissions again.

Anyone got a clue that would point me in the right direction? How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a problem concerning cookies stored with `UIWebView`.
Removing the cookies in the cookie store with `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval` as url resolved it.

Here is the simplified code I use to remove the corresponding cookies after I get the **authorization code** from the page title:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

NSArray *cookies = [storage cookiesForURL:[[_webView request] URL]];

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies)
{
    [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really think should not use the UIWebView. It forces the user to enter a password (and OTP for 2 factor) and a bad user experience and bad from a security point of view. You can either redirect to the safari browser and get a token back see
https://plus.google.com/+NaveenAgarwal/posts/AztHNnQh7w6

or use Google+ SDK. It'll redirect to one of the existing Google app or to the browser and get you  a token.

Comment: Googles own oauth2 client which is used in the Google+ SDK also uses a UIWebView to my knowledge. (see https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/ and the YouTube app).

Comment: Yes, that was written a few years ago when other options were not possible. Now there are better options available and new clients should use them. Using the sdk means a user will just have to click accept. Entering the userid, pw is quite painful for user on each app.